# Problem in javascript classlist toggle function

Tags: javascript, responsive-design, navbar

i want to make responsive sliding nav bar and i did it but when i click on link it doesn't go in main position

here is link of that nav bar reduce size of browser window  and click on home and again click on burgur to toggle but it is not working:
https://yash10800.github.io/Portfolio/

https://github.com/yash10800/Portfolio.git
please solve my doubt

Comment: Please paste the relevant code to the problem here in the question, instead of pasting a link to your whole project.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that, when you are clicking the `home` link, there are 2 classes added to the navigation `ul.nav-links` which are `nav-active` & `nav-deactive`.

When you click on the `burger` icon then only `nav-active` class is toggled but the `nav-deactive` remains.

Remove both of these classes and that should do it.